clang-format: how to wrap braces only for empty body of functions/if/for/while/etc
I want to wrap braces only for empty body of functions and control statements. For instance, I want:
if (true) {
   // not empty
}

void func() {
   // no empty
}

but
if (true) // empty
{}

void func() // empty
{}

How do I achieve this?

There might be a clang-format option to do this, but I don't know about it. Clang-format does not have options to please everyones custom style under the sun. I find that the easiest path is to to tweak it's options to what is closest to what I want and then just live with the few stylistic oddities that it does different - just having it auto format my code for me to 90+% of what I want is a hell of a lot better than having to format everything by hand, so I've learned to just live with a few odd corners.

@JesperJuhl that's a good take, but when there's many developers who are used to one style, it makes sense to dive deep into formating and not to reteach all the team

The result you want to reach is possible if the opening brace of the record has already been wrapped.
Please, take a loot at the Documentation
Find the BraceWrapping option.
Also take a look at SplitEmptyFunction, SplitEmptyRecord and SplitEmptyNamespace
Fortunately, Clang-format gives a lot variants of brace formatting. but it is not almighty. The strongest and weakest part of Clang-format is its simplicity. It's just a text formatting tool and has no idea about the context. You should always keep this in mind when working with it.
Clang-format is a simple but great tool, which formats the code almost nicely, but you always need to re-check manually, to get the best result (and avoid potential errors).

I know about SplitEmpty..., but the problem that I don't want to wrap if body not empty, but I do want to wrap if the body is empty. As I see it's not possible with clang-format, but maybe it's possible to do that with other tools, like clang-tidy or other?
